# php can't get data from #.ajax post in Jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile to develop a small website. Now I want to pass variables from javascript to php. I am using #.ajax post

Here is my code in javascript:

```
var link_id = $(".templateLink").attr("id");
var link_name = $(".templateLink").attr("name");

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data: {id:link_id, name:link_name},
    success: function(){
    //do sth.
    }
});
```

Here is my php code:

```
<?php    
    $survey_link_id = $_POST["id"]; 
    $survey_link_name =  $_POST["name"];
?>
```

However, I keep getting this error:

Notice: Undefined index: id in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iQ_1/test.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: name in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iQ_1/test.php on line 4

It is really annoying. Is it because I'm using jquery mobile??
Can anyone help me?  Or provide other ways to pass variable from javascript to php.

Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: Can you debug ? `var_dump($_POST)` and what you get ?

Comment: I got "array(0) { }". I think the ajax doesn't work

Comment: So, try to figure it out.

Comment: don't know how, I did everything i could, get stuck for hours, follow the rules where someone else has the same problem, but it just doesn't work in my computer..

Comment: Try running `$.post('test.php', {id:1, name: 'test'}, function(resp){ console.log(resp); });` in your console

Comment: could you be more specific how to running this code in the console? sorry, new to web development :)

Comment: @Kevin264: For example, in Chrome, press F12, choose console window, copy paste this code there and hit 'enter'.

Comment: I got this error: "TypeError: Object function bound(var_args) { return func.apply(thisObject, args.concat(slice(arguments))); } has no method 'post'"

Comment: Make sure your link_id and link_name are not null before ajax-call.
Try console.log(link_id); and console.log(link_name); before $.ajax.

Comment: Yep, I checked those two, they are not null. Both have some string.

Comment: hmmmm...
Try data:{id:1, name: "NAME"} instead of data: {id:link_id, name:link_name}. Is it result the same?

Comment: still the same, I got "array(0) { }" when running "var_dump($_POST)" in php. By the way, is the url right? The two files are in the same folder.

Comment: URL look fine, Try jQuery.ajax instead of $.ajax.

Comment: Instead of using "id" and "name" try using something else .. say "a" and "b"

Comment: Still not working, is it because I am using Jquery Mobile framework?

Answer (score 0):

i think u can use set data like this

```
data: "id="+link_id+"&name="+link_name,
```

because i'm using this for post the variable with ajax jquery every time and running nice...

Comment: didn't work in my computer, is it because I am using Jquery Mobile framework?

Comment: Hi, is it I am using rel='external'. That's why the $.ajax wont work?